# jquery: how to get datas from elements without looping?

Tags: jquery

```
$('input:checkbox:checked')
```

Provides me an array (3 items) of checked input as an array.

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').data('userid')
```

This provide me the data-userid of the FIRST checked input. result = 1

Is there a way to get datas of ALL checked inputs WITHOUT having to write a loop ?
ex: 
[1,2,3]

Comment: by `without looping`, you also mean no `jQuery.each()` I presume?

Comment: Don't think there is, using loops whole my js life, as .data or .val returns single value as far as I know. You could give .map or .reduce a try I suppose they work with arrays and jQuery selectors do return you arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not at all possible to get values without looping on them.

You can avoid traditional loop. If you looking for a cleaner solution use map function

---

```js
var result = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('userid');
}).get();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" userid="1" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  
  <input type="checkbox" userid="2" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have two legs<br>
```

Comment: got somethign similar
var result  = $("selector").map(function(el, i){
 return el.value;
})

Comment: However be aware of browser support

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own function to jquery to avoid code duplication.
Try this:

```
$.fn.extend({
           pluckAttr: function (attr) {
              return $(this).map(function(){
                   return $(this).attr(attr);
               }).get();
           }
       });
$('input:checkbox:checked').pluckAttr('data-userid');
```